# Problems installing GMMAT package into R-Studio v. 1.2.5033 & R-console v.3.6.0

Tags: r, install.packages

This is the code I have been running: (as suggested)

```
install.packages (c("devtools", "RcppArmadillo", "CompQuadForm", "doMC", 
                    "foreach", "Matrix", "BiocManager", "testthat"), 
                  repos = "http://cran.r-project.org/")
BiocManager::install(c("SeqArray", "SeqVarTools"))
devtools::install_github("hanchenphd/GMMAT")
```

I receive the subsequent messages in my console:

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need
>   compilation   of C/C++/Fortran: ‘GMMAT’ Do you want to attempt to
>   install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel)

```
Enter: YES
```

And then:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘GMMAT’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/GMMAT’**
```

I have attempted to uninstall and re-install R-Studio and R-console, have updated the platforms, installed any necessary packages for R/Macbook, etc. and still cannot seem to fix this issue. Currently using a Macbook so domc is not the issue.

Any help you guys could provide would be great!

Comment: `devtools` has quite some dependencies and debugging can bit time consuming at first. Try installing each package, one by one, so you can better follow the error messages to install the missing dependencies (curl, openssl, etc.).

Comment: Try `remotes` instead of `devtools` as it has fewer dependencies.

Comment: After taking @Trusky advice, I was error free until this line : devtools::install_github("hanchenphd/GMMAT") 

Then received: 
...
Error: Failed to install 'GMMAT' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/53/k0dt4np56dn99_ym2fm8_7640000gn/T//RtmpoqAOu3/file17ef73921fc6a/GMMAT_1.2.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Tried 'remotes' and still receiving the same non-zero exit status

Comment: Do you get the same error if installing from cran instead of github? It's easy to miss an error btw since they are not necessarily R errors and they pop up fast, are you sure you did not get any `non-zero exit status` error after installing any of the other packages ? I found this quite frustrating at first :\

Comment: Yes same error while installing from cran as well. No errors previous did a thorough search through all the output. Could 
"Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran. Install from these sources?" Have anything to do with it?

Comment: I installed the precompiled binaries from CRAN and have installed GMMAT, when i try to assign the library i receive Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GMMAT’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object 
...

dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/GMMAT/libs/GMMAT.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/GMMAT/libs/GMMAT.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: [This](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-shared-object-on-startup-in-rstudio-only/33107), [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-shared-object/67466/7) and specially [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/every-libraries-failed-to-load-after-upgrading-r-to-3-6-0/29736) might help. It looks like the problem arises after upgrading R.